# Looking for a discrete distribution with a specific mean-variance relationship

Tags: variance, count-data, overdispersion, discrete-distributions

Say we have some counts $Y$ for which the mean-variance relationship is

$$
Var[Y] = \alpha E[Y] + \beta E[Y]^2.
$$

From this, we can say that:

- If $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 0$, then $Y$ can be modeled as a Poisson.
- If $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta > 0$, then $Y$  can be modeled as a Negative Binomial.

However, I was not able to find any distribution for the case where $\alpha \ne 1$ and $\beta > 0$. Ideally, I would love to know if such a distribution has been previously described, and if so, where I could find a description of it (probability mass function, parameter estimation procedure, *etc*.)

Some extra information. Looking at the [GAMLSS](https://www.gamlss.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/DistributionsForModellingLocationScaleandShape.pdf) documentation on count distributions, in section 5.5, they show that if $Y$ is a mixture Poisson, then that $\alpha$ would have to be equal to one. This would suggest that the distribution I am looking for is not a mixture Poisson.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This would actually be an overdispersed negative binomial, because your parametrization of the variance is equivalent to one with a disperson parameter given by:

$$Var[Y] = \psi (E[Y] + \gamma E[Y]^2)$$

where $\psi$ is quickly recognized as the dispersion parameter. As is often the case in quasilikelihood, the estimation routine does not correspond to maximizing a likelihood, but the parameter estimates and predictions are valid and provide asymptotically consistent inference.

To actually estimate this model with software, you will need to define a custom routine.